# Could not open socket

Tags: php, phpbb

I get an error after clicking submit on the registration page:

> Could not open socket

Haven't really changed anything. what could be the reason ? and solution ? :S

Comment: Which registration page?

Comment: It is good if you are putting some more details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the reCAPTCHA plugin fails to connect to the reCAPTCHA server. Your server may not support opening a connection to remote hosts.

Either find out why the connection is failing or use a different CAPTCHA module (spambot countermeasures in the admin control panel).

Comment: seems to be working now..I used a new reCAPTCHA keys

Comment: +1 Nice solution for that many information in the question.

Comment: igorw understood the question with means it was understandable. thanks igor.